# How would i change this code to allow more than one user input message to be sent between the client and server

Tags: java, networking, network-programming

I've just started with both java and networking with servers and clients. Although i understand the basics of whats going on, i was struggling to put it all together and do what i wanted to do in the title. 
I was able to make this to send a message to the server, however i was wondering how i'd turn the message into a input string from the user, and also how id send multiple messages between the client and server
thanks

SERVER

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server {

//Main Method:- called when running the class file.
public static void main(String[] args){ 

    //Portnumber:- number of the port we wish to connect on.
    int portNumber = 15882;
    try{
        //Setup the socket for communication and accept incoming communication
        ServerSocket serverSoc = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
        Socket soc = serverSoc.accept();

        //Catch the incoming data in a data stream, read a line and output it to the console
        DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("--> " + dataIn.readUTF());

        //Remember to close the socket once we have finished with it.
        soc.close();
    }
    catch (Exception except){
        //Exception thrown (except) when something went wrong, pushing message to the console
        System.out.println("Error --> " + except.getMessage());
    }
}}
```

CLIENT

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


public class Client {

//Main Method:- called when running the class file.
public static void main(String[] args){ 

    //Portnumber:- number of the port we wish to connect on.
    int portNumber = 15882;
    //ServerIP:- IP address of the server.
    String serverIP = "localhost";

    try{
        //Create a new socket for communication
        Socket soc = new Socket(serverIP,portNumber);

        //Create the outputstream to send data through
        DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());

        //Write message to output stream and send through socket
        dataOut.writeUTF("Hello other world!");
        dataOut.flush();

        //close the data stream and socket 
        dataOut.close();
        soc.close();
    }
    catch (Exception except){
        //Exception thrown (except) when something went wrong, pushing message to the console
        System.out.println("Error --> " + except.getMessage());
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some "problems" with your code.

1. You should only close the ServerSocket if you are done.
2. You should handle the newly connected client inside a thread to allow multiple clients to simultaniously "send messages".

---

## 1.

you could easily wrap your code inside an while loop.

```
boolean someCondition = true;
try{
    //Setup the socket for communication and accept incoming communication
    ServerSocket serverSoc = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
    // repeat the whole process over and over again.
    while(someCondition) {
        Socket soc = serverSoc.accept();

        //Catch the incoming data in a data stream, read a line and output it to the console
        DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("--> " + dataIn.readUTF());
    }

    //Remember to close the socket once we have finished with it.
    soc.close();
}
```

Now your programm should continue to accept clients. But only one at a time. You can now terminate the Server by stopping the programm or by changing the `someCondition` to false and accepting the next client.

A bit more advanced would be, to shutdown the ServerSocket to stop the programm and catching the exception inside the while loop.

---

## 2.

To allow multiple clients to be handled simultaniously, you should pack the handle part into another Thread.

```
private ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

boolean someCondition = true;
try{
    //Setup the socket for communication and accept incoming communication
    ServerSocket serverSoc = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
    // repeat the whole process over and over again.
    while(someCondition) {
        Socket soc = serverSoc.accept();

            //Catch the incoming data in a data stream, read a line and output it to the console in a new Thread.
        threadPool.submit(() -> {
            DataInputStream dataIn = new 
            DataInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("--> " + dataIn.readUTF());
        }
    }

    //Remember to close the socket once we have finished with it.
    soc.close();
}
```

The part inside the `threadPool.submit` block could be specified as an custom instance of the Runnable interface of as an method, to call it using [method reference](https://www.codementor.io/eh3rrera/using-java-8-method-reference-du10866vx).
I assumed you are knowing about ThreadPools. [They have multiple advantages over Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700763/thread-pool-vs-many-individual-threads)

This should get you going for any number of clients.

Note: This is not good designed, but it is for demonstrational porpurses only.